# Carbon initial date value

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-carbon

Maybe I'm not seeing the forest because of the trees but here's what I am facing:

```
$week_start = new Carbon();
$week_start->setISODate($year,$week);  //2016 , 21

$init = $week_start; //I am assigning the datetime created to $init variable (1)

$min_sqldate = $week_start->toDateString(); //string of date
$max_sqldate = $week_start->addDays(6)->toDateString(); //string of date adding 6 days
```

At this point `$init` variable already has a value of `$max_sqldate`. (2)

How is this possible? How should I keep my initial variable so I can use it later on ?

Value of `$init` in case (1):

```
 Carbon {#328 ▼
      +"date": "2016-05-23 16:58:36.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/Helsinki"
    }
```

Value of `$init` in case (2):

```
 Carbon {#328 ▼
      +"date": "2016-05-29 17:00:34.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/Helsinki"
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain why are you doing this `$init = $week_start;` and what do you expect from the **$init** variable?

Comment: I would expect that in any programming language if `a = b`, then `b=anything` then the value of `a` to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carbon provides a `copy()` method that will return a "fresh" copy of the instance, e.g.

```
$init = $week_start->copy();
```

By default in PHP, when copying an object using equals, you won't end up with an independent copy. You can also work around this using the `clone` keyword.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: So when working with objects using equals it's creating a pointer to the first object instead of creating a new object, just like doing `$a = &$b;`

I didn't knew that! Thank you!